# Trying to copy lines from text file to array of strings (char**)

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code for allocating memory for the array of strings:

```
FileReader::FileReader()
{
    readBuffer = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        readBuffer[i] = (char*)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Im alocating 100 strings for 100 lines then allocating 200 chars for each string.

This is my code for reading the lines:

```
char** FileReader::ReadFile(const char* filename)
{
    int i = 0;

    File.open(filename);

    if (File.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(File, tmpString))
        {
            readBuffer[i] = (char*)tmpString.c_str();
            i++;
        }
        return readBuffer;
    }
    
}
```

and for printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << fileCpy[i];
    }
```

this is the output to terminal:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gehSz.png)

As you can see it just repeats the last line of the file as the file just reads:
**This is test
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5**

Any idea on whats going on? Why the lines aren't copying correctly?

Comment: Why are you manually allocating arrays of arrays with `malloc` in a program that has access to `std::getline`/`std::string`? Even if it works (which it doesn't, because you didn't properly copy from `.c_str()` to the preallocated buffer, instead *replacing* the buffer with the result of `.c_str()` that expires as soon as `tmpString` does), it doesn't serve a useful purpose.

Comment: Any objection to reworking this to use the modern `std::string` instead of building strings the way the ancients did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
readBuffer[i] = (char*)tmpString.c_str();
```

with

```
strcpy(readBuffer[i], tmpString.c_str());
```

Your version just saves a pointers to `tmpString` in your array. When `tmpString` changes then that pointer points at the new contents of `tmpString` (and that's just the best possible outcome). However `strcpy` actually copies the characters of the string, which is what you want.

Of course, I'm sure it doesn't need saying, but you can avoid all the headache and complication like this

```
vector<string> readBuffer;
```

This way there are no more pointer problems, no more manual allocation or freeing of memory, no limits, you aren't limited to 100 lines or 200 characters per line. I'm sure you have a reason for doing things the hard way. but I wonder if it's a good reason.

Comment: Of note: When `tmpString.size() >= 200`, this is a guaranteed buffer overflow that would almost certainly lead to heap corruption and security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Dude you're goated. To be honest, if you couldn't tell already im quite new and I havent even tried using vector. I've heard of it but never tried it.

Comment: @SNG To add a string to a vector `readBuffer.push_back(tmpString)`. To get the size of a vector `readBuffer.size()`, apart from that you can use them pretty much exactly like arrays,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to switch from C to C++.

Do not allocate memory like that when the only way to do it now in modern C++ is trough smart pointers from the memory header.

Anyways, you do not directly  need dynamic allocation here. You have to encapsulate your data within the class and to use the std::vector<std::string> component from the standard library. This vector is a dynamic array that handle all the memory stuff behind the scene for you.

To read all lines of a file :

```
std::string item_name;
std::vector<std::string> your_buffer;
std::ifstream name_fileout;

name_fileout.open("test.txt");

while (std::getline(name_fileout, item_name))
{
    your_buffer.push_back(item_name);
    std::cout << item_name;
}

name_fileout.close();
```

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying. I haven't even touched smart pointers and std::vector. I'm really new.

Comment: @SNO check this link for the std::vector https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
 Once you used the push_back method to insert elements at the end of the array (aka the vector), you can access those elements with the operator [] like any regular array (but you can't access elements through [] if they don't exist being given you'd then be trying to access a memory location that is not part of the vector yet)

Comment: So like, what smart pointers should I use as well? I was looking at them and I was completely lost. I was mainly looking at unique_ptr and shared_ptr

Comment: @SNO if you're new to C++, you should be dealing with things that give results quickly like vectors and strings, not pointers, memory allocation and C-style string functions.

Comment: @stefaanv youre probably right however I want to stay very very low level.

Comment: @SNO C is even more low level and nobody will comment on you using low level constructs in C.